# waiting on asynchronous http requests in java

Tags: java, http, asynchronous, jetty

I'm using Jetty HTTP Client to make about 50 HTTP calls asynchronously.  The code looks something like this:

```
List<Address> addresses = getAddresses();
final List<String> done = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());
List<ContentExchange> requests;
for (Address address : addresses) {
    ContentExchange ce = new ContentExchange() {
        @Override
        protected void onResponseComplete() throws IOException {
            //handle response
            done.add("done");
        }
    }
    ce.setURL(createURL(address));
    requests.add(ce);
}
for (ContentExchange ce : requests) {
    httpClient.send(ce);
}

while (done.size() != addresses.size()) {
    Thread.yield();
}

System.out.println("All addresses processed");
```

It's calling a rest service that returns back some data about the address.  What I expect it to do is this:

1. Make 50 asynchronous (non-blocking) http calls.
2. The thread will wait until all 50 are finished.

However, it's not working.  It works fine if I don't have the while loop, but I need to wait until all 50 are done.  Is there some way to wait until all 50 are done?

Also I know about ExecutorService and multiple thread solution, but I need a single thread solution with non-blocking IO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to manage this.

Example from [Eclipse Jetty 8.1.10.v20130312's Siege.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-8.1.10.v20130312/jetty-client/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/client/Siege.java#L215-L225) test class:

```java
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(concurrent);   

for (int i=0;i<concurrent;i++)
{
    ConcurrentExchange ex = new ConcurrentExchange(client,latch,uris,repeats);
    if (!ex.next()) // this executes the client.send()
    {
        latch.countDown(); // count down if client.send() was in error
    }
}

latch.await(); // wait for all ConcurrentExchange's to complete (or error out)
```

Note: [ConcurrentExchange](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-8.1.10.v20130312/jetty-client/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/client/Siege.java#L37) is a private class within Siege.java.

Then in your [`HttpExchange`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpExchange.html) object, use the [`CountDownLatch.countDown()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#countDown%28%29) call in the following methods

- [onConnectionFailed(Throwable x)](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpExchange.html#onConnectionFailed%28java.lang.Throwable%29) - [example](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-8.1.10.v20130312/jetty-client/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/client/Siege.java#L64)
- [onException(Throwable x)](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpExchange.html#onException%28java.lang.Throwable%29) - example
- [onExpire()](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpExchange.html#onExpire%28%29) - example
- [onResponseComplete()](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpExchange.html#onResponseComplete%28%29) - example

Note that all of the examples use a [`AtomicBoolean counted`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-8.1.10.v20130312/jetty-client/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/client/Siege.java#L50) to make sure that they are only counted once.

```java
if (!counted.getAndSet(true)) // get the value, then set it to true
{
    // only get here if counted returned false. (and that will only happen once)
    latch.countDown(); // count down this exchange as being done.
}
```